# Vaadin + Polymer Component Does Not Render Correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, polymer, vaadin

To begin with, I'm not comfortable at all with front-end technologies. I'm trying to make a Vaadin view based on a polymer template. Problem is that the result is not what I'm expecting. When I preview the page without Vaadin and Polymer (Classic HTML + CSS), the result is this:

[image]

But when using Polymer I get this when I go that route with Vaadin:

[image]

I suspect I may be making some mistake in the way I import my CSS. Here is my Polymer code:

```js
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

class NotFoundView extends PolymerElement {

    static get template() {
        return html`
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
            <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
            <style>
                @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans");
                :root {
                    --blue: #0e0620;
                    --white: #fff;
                    --green: #2ccf6d;
                }

                html,
                body {
                    height: 100%;
                }

                body {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                    font-family: "Nunito Sans";
                    color: var(--blue);
                    font-size: 1em;
                }

                button {
                    font-family: "Nunito Sans";
                }

                h1 {
                    font-size: 7.5em;
                    margin: 15px 0px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                }

                h2 {
                    font-weight: bold;
                }


                .btn {
                    z-index: 1;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    position: relative;
                    padding: 8px 50px;
                    border-radius: 30px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    font-size: 1em;
                    letter-spacing: 2px;
                    transition: 0.2s ease;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    margin: 5px 0px;
                }


                @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                    body {
                        display: block;
                    }

                    margin-bottom: 70px;
                    .container {
                        margin-top: 70px;
                    }
                }
            </style>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
                        <img src="/images/ancient.jpg" style="max-width: 80%; max-height: 80%; "alt="Ancient" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
                        <h1>404</h1>
                        <h2>UH OH! You're lost.</h2>
                        <p>The page you are looking for does not exist.
                            How you got here is a mystery. But you can click the button below
                            to go back to the homepage.
                        </p>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">HOME</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
`;
    }

    static get is() {
        return 'not-found-view';
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            // Declare your properties here.
        };
    }
}

customElements.define(NotFoundView.is, NotFoundView);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer uses shadow roots which means that the CSS inside the element is encapsulated to only apply to the contents of that element. In particular, it means that the styles targeted to `html` and `body` are never applied since those elements are not inside this element.

You can to some degree fix this by changing the CSS to use the `:host` selector instead, but I cannot guess whether that would be enough for all the cases (especially the media queries). The `:host` selector applies to the element that the shadow root is attached to, i.e. the `not-found-view` element itself.

As an alternative, you could extract the global CSS to a separate file that is loaded as regular CSS rather than inside the element's shadow root.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot to understand what is going on there. I'm still confused on how can I make the media query work. If I import it with `@CssImport` in Vaadin then it will become global and may cause a mess. If I use the `themeFor` property of the annotation then wouldn't be the same thing as the above code ?

Comment: `themeFor` is mostly intended as a way of getting CSS into the shadow root of a reusable component (such as any built-in `vaadin-something` component) where you cannot simply modify the source of the component itself.

Comment: Your problem with the media query is most likely not directly related to shadow roots, but rather the typical single-page application structure where the global CSS from one part of the application remains loaded even if some other part of the application is loaded. One typical way of dealing with that is to toggle e.g. a class name of the body element based on which part is in use and then write the CSS to be dependent on that class name.